# mvc routing to incorrect url on http post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The default url of the application is 
http://servername/Root/ITProjects

There is a menu item with 'Team' on the default page which should redirect to another controller with index which will display a dropdownlist at the following url

http://servername/Root/ITProjects/Team

It's working fine so far.

However when the user selects an item in the dropdownlist, it should go to the url below
http://servername/Root/ITProjects/Team/Index?Id=7

But it's directing to
http://servername/Team/Index?Id=7

and throwing the 404 error. It is missing the folder path 'Root/ITProjects' after the servername. It's working fine on localhost where there is no folder path but failing on deployment to test or prod servers

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "APP_xxxx_Users")]
public class TeamController : Controller
{
    public int pageSize = 5;
    private IProjectService _projectService;

    public TeamController(IProjectService projectService)
    {
        this._projectService = projectService;
    }
    public ActionResult Index(int? Id, int? page)
    {
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var viewModel = new TeamViewModel();
        if (Id != null)
        {
            viewModel.SelectedMember = (int)Id;
            viewModel.Tasks = this._projectService.GetTasksByStaff(viewModel.SelectedMember).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);             
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult IndexPost(int Id, int? page)
    {
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    var viewModel = new TeamViewModel();
    viewModel.SelectedMember = Id;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Tasks = this._projectService.GetTasksByStaff(viewModel.SelectedMember).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
    return View(viewModel);
    }
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

As part of Index view when dropdownlist item is selected

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMember, new SelectList(Model.StaffList, "UniqueId", "Initials", Model.SelectedMember), new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-color", onchange = @"form.action='/Team/Index?Id=' +this.value;form.submit();" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MVC application is in a sub-directory of another application, so IIS considers the root of the parent application instead of the root of your MVC application.

In IIS, you need to convert the virtual directory to an Application: choose your virtual directory and "Convert to Application." If you are unable to do that, then you need to modify your routes in routes.config to take the virtual directory into account:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "Root/ITProjects/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: I did convert virtual directory to application. As I mentioned (updated just now) in the post, there is no issue with default and redirecting to other controller index method. It's failing only when there is a http post from other controller. when I did change the route.config to Root/ITProjects/...., it is throwing 404 error on all pages

Comment: What does your form look like in the view?  More specifically, how are you constructing the POST url in the form?  Finally, look at the rendered form in Dev Tools - what is the post URL?

Comment: I have  posted the dropdownlistfor on the index view at the bottom of the post. Based on the selected item, I am calling onchange event.

Comment: Your post is going to exactly where you asked: `form.action='/Team/Index`.  You need to update the post to `form.action='/Root/ITProjects/Team/Index`

Comment: But there would be different folder structure in localhost, test and prod environments. Is there any generic way to identify the folder structure based on the environment the application is in and redirect accordingly.

Comment: The different environments will continue to give you problems by hard coding an action URL.  Try removing the action URL specification  altogether - it should then post to the URL the form did a GET from.

Answer (score 0):

your default route for controllers looks like this :

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

You can add /Root/ITProjects/ before the URL to change the default controller path